# Loading JS from other Javascript without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im using Google chart for which i need to load the google's loader JS which is found in theirs link. I need to load this to header part of HTML using JS, but as the page loads the js runs and only the script tag is added to header but the google loader link in script tag will not be connected and not useable until i commit anything in the page.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: Hi Roberrrt, actually im using a modeling tool called Tacton, and TC site tool to render the modeling. TC site will render the fields from modeling and creates the HTML content. Im creating a plugin to add any content to HTML. Plugin is loading the script tag < SCRIPT type="text/javascript" scr="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"> to header but loader JS will not be loaded as page loads for 1st time. after any commit in page the link will be loaded but it will be present in 1st load at header but not loaded.